# I can't get my json file as "pretty" JSON using iPython

Tags: python, json, ipython

I am using `from IPython.display import JSON` to have an organized `json`. However, I get the following:

```
<IPython.core.display.JSON object>
```

my code:

```
from IPython.display import JSON
with open("world_bank_projects.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

JSON(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with ipython for JSON pretty-printing, just use the builtin feature known as the `indent` parameter in `json.dumps`:

```py
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: I got this :

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

Comment: Sounds like your JSON file is too large to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JupyterLab instead of Jupiter. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).